# Sass local compile doesn't work, codepen works

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to compile this little piece of .scss code:

```
$main-color:#06c;

:root{
        --main-color-05: adjust-color($main-color, $lightness: +51%);}
```

---

When i compile i get this results:

**local** (sass -v: Sass 3.5.2 (Bleeding Edge))

```
:root {
  --main-color-05: adjust-color($main-color, $lightness: +51%); }
```

**Codepen** ([here's the code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vezNMO))

```
:root {
  --main-color-05: #d1e8ff;}
```

---

Local compiler seems to **ignore adjust-color function** in custom properties, which works in class declarations:

```
$main-color:#06c;

:root{
        --main-color-05: adjust-color($main-color, $lightness: +51%);}

.main-color-05{
    background-color: adjust-color($main-color, $lightness: +51%);}
```

---

(compiled)

```
:root {
      --main-color-05: adjust-color($main-color, $lightness: +51%); }

    .main-color-05 {
      background-color: #d1e8ff; }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use some sass mixin to set custom properties. Please have a look

https://codepen.io/malyw/pen/aNwKKv

```
// SCSS
$rootVars: ();

@mixin setVarSass($varName, $value){
  $rootVars: map-merge($rootVars, (
    #{$varName}: $value
  )) !global;
}

@function getVarSass($varName){
  @return map-get($rootVars, #{$varName});
}

@include setVarSass("color", #f00);

// CSS
@mixin setVarCss($varName, $value){
  @supports ( (--a: 0)) {
    // Custom properties are supported in the browser
    $varName: unquote($varName);
    :root{
      #{--$varName}: $value;
    }
  }
}

@function getVarCss($varName){
  $varName: unquote($varName);
  @return #{var(--$varName)};
}

// Common
@mixin setVar($varName, $value){
  @include setVarSass($varName, $value);
  @include setVarCss($varName, $value);
}

@mixin setPropFromVar($propName, $varName){
  @supports ( (--a: 0)) {
    // Custom properties are supported in the browser
    #{$propName}: getVarCss($varName);
  }

  @supports ( not (--a: 0)) {    
    // Custom properties are NOT supported in the browser
    #{$propName}: getVarSass($varName);
  }
}

// SET/GET
@include setVar('main-color', #f00);

body {
  @include setPropFromVar('color', 'main-color');
}
```

or use npm module like

- https://github.com/malyw/css-vars
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-properties-sass